# Mysql - reorder / reset position key

Tags: mysql

I have a MySQL table with position key (65,000 records). I deleted, updated some rows in the middle of the table. Now I have, for example, something like this in the position `1 - 6 - 2 - 9`

| id | category | position |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 | 6 |
| 3 | 2 | 2 |
| 4 | 2 | 9 |

I want to reset / reorder the position key

| id | category | position |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 | 2 |
| 3 | 2 | 1 |
| 4 | 2 | 2 |

How can I reset position where category = 1
and where category = 2?

Comment: @yusuf hayırsever yes, but I have `#1064 - Something is wrong in your syntax` I put it on phpmysql console. I changed source_table to photographs.

Comment: can you try again?

Comment: @yusuf hayırsever same `#1064 - Something is wrong in your syntax` maybe I'm doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```sql
UPDATE source_table
JOIN ( SELECT id, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY category ORDER BY position) position 
       FROM source_table ) subquery USING (id)
SET source_table.position = subquery.position
```

> mysql> SHOW VARIABLES LIKE "%version%"; 5.7.24 – sagittarius

```sql
UPDATE source_table
JOIN ( SELECT t1.id, COUNT(t2.id) position
       FROM source_table t1
       JOIN source_table t2 ON t1.category = t2.category
                           AND t1.position >= t2.position
       GROUP BY t1.id ) subquery USING (id)
SET source_table.position = subquery.position;
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=1d8e278d8b39e778029208b921dd3bea)

> if position is duplicated everything crashes – sagittarius

```sql
UPDATE source_table
JOIN ( SELECT t1.id, COUNT(t2.id) position
       FROM source_table t1
       JOIN source_table t2 ON t1.category = t2.category
                           AND (    t1.position > t2.position
                                 OR (     t1.position = t2.position
                                      AND t1.id >= t2.id ))
       GROUP BY t1.id ) subquery USING (id)
SET source_table.position = subquery.position;
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=64805e578973d0b3392d82c88b154f6e)

Comment: @Thank you for your answer, how to use it? In the mysql console I have `#1064 - Something is wrong in your syntax`

Comment: @sagittarius Specify **PRECISE** MySQL version.

Comment: @Akina `mysql> SHOW VARIABLES LIKE "%version%";` `5.7.24`

Comment: @sagittarius You should have started your question with this information! wait... done.

Comment: @Akina Now it is no error, but everywhere position is `1` `category = 1 position 1,1,1,1 category = 2 position 1,1,1,1` and it should be `category = 1 position 1,2,3,4 category = 2 position 1,2,3,4`

Comment: @sagittarius Misprint. Fixed. PS. And I do not see the info about server version in your question yet...

Comment: @Akina it works, but if I have on position twice the same number `2,2` then it will replace everything with `2`.

Comment: @sagittarius Add check by `id` to the joining condition if positions are equal.

Comment: @Akina now as i have everywhere `1` in `category =1  I have everywhere 34, in category =2 everywhere 14`

Comment: @sagittarius Create a fiddle with your data and query similar to the fiddle in the answer and provide a link.

Comment: @Akina `https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=10f6de9932402a47264cfe595088296b`

Comment: @Akina I don't know if I presented it well to you, if position is duplicated everything crashes

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE source_table t1
INNER JOIN
(
   SELECT id,category,position, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY category 
       ORDER BY position) position2 
       FROM source_table 
) t2
    ON t2.id = t1.id
SET
    t1.position = t2.position2
```

I think this code is easy to understand and apply.

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply. [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/27780780)